# Diferença de Session em Java

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Qual é diferença de `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` e `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped`?

Alguém sabe explicar?

Comment: aqui tem uma boa resposta (em inglês...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057564/why-are-there-different-bean-management-annotations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A anotação `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped` deve ser adicionada a `ManagedBean`s do JSF para denotar que o bean tem um escopo de sessão. Ou seja, que a instância do bean é mantida na sessão.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que você tenha:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped
public class MeuBean implements java.io.Serializable {
    // Um monte de métodos.
}
```

E então em várias páginas do seu (X)HTML, você tem uma expressão `meuBean`. Essa instância `meuBean` estará armazenada na sessão. Cada requisição de um mesmo cliente vai trazer a mesma instância com os mesmos dados e ao alterar uma, a alteração vai se refletir em todas as requisições desse cliente. Entretanto clientes diferentes terão instâncias diferentes desse bean.

Já o `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` é uma anotação do CDI a ser colocada em atributos e métodos para denotar que o atributo ou método em questão armazena ou produz algum recurso que é o mesmo em cada sessão. Normalmente é usado em classes do tipo *factory* juntamente com a anotação `@Produces`. Isso serve para que na injeção de dependências com o `@Inject`, quando um mesmo recurso for ser injetado em vários locais, para que o método da *factory* não seja invocado para cada um desses locais. Ele será invocado só na primeira vez e o resultado será armazenado na sessão, para ser reutilizado em cada injeção a ser realizada naquela sessão.

Exemplo que peguei da apostila da Caelum que linkei abaixo:

```
public class ProdutorEntityManager {

   @Produces @RequestScoped
   public EntityManager criaEntityManager() {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Referências:

- https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/
- http://blog.caelum.com.br/use-cdi-no-seu-proximo-projeto-java/